# UserDefault in Xcode is not saving the text

Tags: xcode, userdefaults

This code won't save the text for same reason. How to fix it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllertextview: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _ = UserDefaults.standard

        let value = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "onekey")
        
        if value != nil{
            text.text = value
            }
        else {
            text.text = "Here you can make Notes"
        }
        
    }
    let defaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
    
    @IBAction func Sbutton(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(text.text, forKey: "onekey")
    }

    
    @IBAction func ggbutton(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

UserDefaults don't immediately write data to storage. You can try calling  `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` to save immediately, right after `UserDefaults.standard.set(..`

Comment: I have tried to add UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you debug it? if you save it like using `UserDefaults.standard.set("value", forKey: "key")` you can get it using `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "key")`.

Comment: If I use UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "key") how to I get the text to text field? I am not so good at coding

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` has been soft-deprecated for quite some time now. Don't use it.